# Is there a better way to constantly rebuild a widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have widget with data that changes regularly and I'm using a Timer.periodic to rebuild the widget. This starts out working smoothly but becomes choppy pretty quickly is there a better way to do this?

```
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  static const Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: 16);

  update(){
    system.updatePos(duration.inMilliseconds/1000);
    setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Timer.periodic(duration, (timer){
      update();
    });


    return PositionField(
      layoutSize: widget.square,
      children: system.map
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why do you want to constantly rebuild?

Comment: @RémiRousselet PositionField has a list of widgets with positions and their positions are being updated with the timer

Comment: And why not use the animation framework?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I don't know very much about the animation framework but I assumed that it would be run once for a duration. I'll look into it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a big mistake:

The `build` method must never have any side effects, because it is called again whenever `setState` is called (or when some higher up widget changes, or when the user rotates the screen...).

Instead, you want to create your `Timer` in `initState`, and cancel it on `dispose`:

```
class TimerTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimerTestState createState() => _TimerTestState();
}

class _TimerTestState extends State<TimerTest> {
  Timer _timer;

  int _foo = 0;

  // this is only called once when the widget is attached
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => _update());
  }

  // stop the timer when the widget is detached and destroyed
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _update() {
    setState(() {
      _foo++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Foo: ${_foo}');
  }
}
```